# Active directory Notes field max character length

Tags: active-directory

Does anyone know what is the max character length in the AD notes field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the Schema of your Active-Directory server

According to the following dialogbox for a W2K8 R2 it's : 32768

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
dsquery * "cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=mydomain,dc=org" -Filter "(LDAPDisplayName=info)" -attr rangeUpper
```

And for the notes/info field it returned:

```
rangeUpper
1024
```

Hope this helps.